# ASP.NET Attempt by method ... to access field 'System.Data.SqlClient.xxx._connection' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, bulkinsert

I'm using a package from NuGet which works on localhost, worked on a production server but after a recent move to a different production server, I get the following error:

`Attempt by method 'EntityFramework.BulkInsert.Extensions.TypeExtensions.GetPrivateFieldValue(System.Object, System.String)' to access field 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection._connectionString' failed.`

The package is: https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/  I don't think it's package specific because using an alternative package for bulk inserts I get a similar error:

`Attempt by method 'Z.Utility.SqlBulkOperation.SetCommonSetting()' to access field 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy._connection' failed.`

The common thing here is `System.Data.SqlClient.xxx._connection failed`

Are there any IIS setting I need to look at? I'm stumped.

Comment: Maybe provide some of your code?

Comment: There's nothing to it really, using the first package `db.BulkInsert(records);`, using the second package `db.SqlBulkInsert(records);`.  The code works, just not on a particular server.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the .NET Trust Levels from Medium to Full in IIS.